# accessing specific part of JSON object with text string of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have performed diff of two json files with the output being an array of strings indicating the location within a json tree.

The original json file is something along the lines of:

```
{
  'key': {
    'key3': 'value'
  },
  'key1': {
    'key2': 'value2'
  }
  'key5': {
    'key4': 'value4'
  }
}
```

And the output of the diff is:

```
[
  'key.key3',
  'key1.key2'
]
```

I'm able to cycle through all the strings in the array:

```
(difference).forEach((k) => {
  console.log(k);
})
```

How do I access the value from the original json file using the strings set by the `forEach()` function above? I want something like what would be returned if I called originalJSON.key1.key2 directly, but it has to be made up by the strings in the above function.

I've tried `originalJSON[k]` but that just returns undefined.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON requires double quotes.

Comment: Ok, thanks, yes you're right. Should have double quotes and seems I'm misled with the terminology of JSON objects.
The suggested 'possible duplicate' should resolve the issue. Thanks @Andreas

Answer (score 3):

You have to split `'key.key3'` into `'key'` and `'key3'`.

One way to do this is just to `'key.key3'.split(".")` which gives `['key','key3']`

Then you can use them to navigate through your original object :

```
(difference).forEach( k => {
  var keys = k.split(".")         // ['key','key3']
  var val = originalJSON[keys[0]][keys[1]] // == originalJSON['key']['key3']
  console.log(val);                        // 'value', 'value2', 'value4'
})
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: You've seen the exact duplicate below the question...?

Comment: In the end I used the function in this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491621/2987737

Comment: @Andreas no I hadn't. It was marked as duplicate after I posted my answer (for that matter, you can't post an answer on a duplicate question).

Comment: @Nicho fair enough